# Route in Linux with 2 card 2 gateways

Tags: linux, route, gateway

This is a new setup:

[image]

The file server can ping the 10.5.4.1 with:

**route add 10.5.4.0 netmask 255.255.252.0 gw 10.5.8.2**

But 10.5.4.1 cannot ping 10.5.8.10.

It's important to know that in the gateway 10.5.8.2 I have added:
**route add 10.5.8.0 netmask 255.255.252.0 gw 10.8.0.2**
10.8.0.2 is the link.
From 10.5.4.1 I can ping **all** computers on 10.5.8.x. (their gateway is 10.5.8.2, so no problem)

I tried many *route add* tests and only when I change the gateway on the server to 10.5.8.2, then 10.5.4.x machines can see the 10.5.8.10

How to simply have the card return request from it's own network? Dual gateway in same system?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the Gateway 10.5.8.2, it doesn't know the path for 10.5.8.10, You have to put a route for it there `route add 10.5.8.10/22 via <one of the computer that has an interface connected to the file server>`

Comment: I have added the 10.5.8.x network to the 10.5.8.2 gateway... I can ping all the network 10.5.8.x from 10.5.4.1... **Except** the file server due to that 2 gateways thing...